# jquery form plugin resubmit won't fire when using upload

Tags: jquery, forms

How can I "live'ify" my jquery (form plugin) upload routine as described below?

The first click uploads and refreshes the list as expected, but the user cannot upload a second file as it seems no to be firing the javascript, I have tried several ".live('submit'" combinations with this plugin but haven't solved:

JQuery uses the form plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
var options = {target: '#uploads_panel', 

                 data:
                     { upload_ajax_on:'1',
                               upload:'1'
                     }
              };

$('#upload-form').submit(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
     return false;
});
});
```

form looks like this:

```
 <div id='uploads_panel'> <!-- for ajax refresh -->
    //table containing existing file list
<form action="/file/upload" method="post" id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>File<br />
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
</div>
```

and the controller looks like this:

```
public function uploadAction()
{

//fetch variables etc

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
$data=array();
$data[name] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$data[internal_name] = date("Y-m-d-h-m-s",time()).$data[name];
$data[type] = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
$data[size] = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$data[path] = 'uploads/'. $_SESSION['customer_id'] . "/".$data[internal_name];
$data[upload_time] = time();
$data[user_id] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$data[customer_id] = $_SESSION['customer_id'];

$tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

$testervar=$uploadDir.$data[internal_name];
$result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $uploadDir.$data[internal_name]);

if (!$result)
{
    echo "Error uploading file";
    die;
}

$db = new DBitems();
 //   $last_id=$db->uploadFile($data);


}

$upload_ajax_on=$_POST['upload_ajax_on'];

$dbitems = new DBitems();
$filelist=$dbitems->selectFilesByCustomerId($_SESSION['customer_id']);
$this->registry->template->filelist =$filelist;


if(isset($upload_ajax_on))
{
$this->registry->template->setView('masterpage','layouts:ajax');
$this->registry->template->setView('contents','customers:table_upload');
}
else
{
$returnurl=$_POST['returnurl'];
$this->registry->router->redirect($returnurl);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried moving the form outside the uploads_panel div? Not sure if that is being affected by the update or not? Hope that helps?

Comment: No probs, glad it sorted things.